# How to access Restricted audio files in Google Drive API to play them in AVPlayer (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, google-api, google-drive-api

In my app I want to be able to play audio files from Google Drive. I do it like this:

```
import AVKit

class MyVC: UIViewController {
...
var player: AVPlayer!
...
private func playTrack() {
   let url = URL(string: "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=open&id=XXXXX" //where XXXXX is an item id
   let playerItem: AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
   player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
   player!.play()
   }
}
```

But it only works with files for which I have previously enabled "Anyone with the link" access in Google Drive.
[image: access]

But I'd like to be able to play files with Restricted access (which is set by default in Google Drive).
To connect my application to Google Drive API I use API Key and OAuth 2.0 Client ID. I request the user for all Scopes that are available to an unverified application. This way I can get a list of the user's files and also download them.
[image: scope1]
[image: scope2]

I know that there are applications that do not require the audio file to have "Anyone with the" access. I tested this on my audio files in Google Drive: this application plays the file with "Restricted" access easily, but my application doesn't. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Google drive is a file storage device its not intended for playing anything.

Comment: @DaImTo  Sorry, but it looks like you misunderstood the question. I don't want to use Google Drive as an audio player - I create the player myself, I just want to get the necessary access to the file and the URL link by which my player can play it.

Comment: Google only creates URL links for some types of files those mainly being the Google doc files.  Audio files are not one.  The links that google does create are opened in Google docs directly, sheets, .....    What i am saying is this is not an access issue this is an Out of scope for Google drive issue.  [download the file](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) and play it locally, you will need authorization and oauth2

Comment: I understand what you're talking about. My application has already implemented the ability to download audio files from Google Drive and play them further. But I'd like to play them online. How can you do this, for example, if you take the link of some file and just paste it in your browser. Try it.
I wouldn't talk about this if I hadn't seen applications that can do this. It's just that, unfortunately, Google's documentation for iOS is too scarce.